# Closing a window in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I have been working on a project with WPF and MVVM for a while now. In a part of my project, I used the following code to close a window. The code works, however, I do not understand the logic behind the code yet. My code is:

```
App.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
    .Where(win => win is DisplayView).FirstOrDefault()
    .Close();
```

Why is FirstOrDefault() required?

Comment: First or default is a safe way to get the first item from a collection.

Comment: You call Where which returns enumerable type, means can contain a lot of elements, and then you choose only first. Replace it as follows FirstOrDefault(win => win is DisplayView).Close()

Answer (score 3):

It just uses some Linq `IEnumerable<T>` extensions to get the first item from a collection that matches a given type, then calls `Close` on that instance.  It is actually needlessly verbose, because this:

```
App.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
    .Where(win => win is DisplayView)
```

is more or less equivalent to this:

```
App.Current.Windows.OfType<DisplayView>()
```

Also, calling `FirstOrDefault()` followed by "Close" is a bit silly.  FirstOrDefault is like `First`, except it returns null instead of throwing an exception if there are no elements -- but in that case it would throw an exception anyway because you'd be calling "Close" on a null object.

---

So I would write it like this:

```
App.Current.Windows.OfType<DisplayView>().First().Close();
```

If you wanted to verify that there is in fact a DisplayView instance, and prevent an exception in that case, then you could use this:

```
var displayViews = App.Current.Windows.OfType<DisplayView>();
if (displayViews.Any())
    displayViews.First().Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's split it:

- `App.Current`: get the running WPF application (should be `Application.Current` I think)
- `.Windows.Cast<Window>()`: get the list of windows but as this is an **untyped collection** make it strongly typed to use all the **LINQ** operators
- `.Where(win => win is DisplayView)`: LINQ operator to filter the windows list and only keep those of type `DisplayView`
- `.FirstOrDefault()`: get the first element of this collection or `null` if there is none
- `.Close()`: close the window we got, this is dangerous as it will blow with a `NullReferenceException` if none was found

Here is a safer approach:

```
DisplayView view = App.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
                                      .Where(win => win is DisplayView)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();

if (view != null)
{
    view.Close();
}
```